# Access HTML form values in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is what I am trying to achieve, but for some reason, it does not work:

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
  function  calculate() {             
     var n1 = getElementById("1").value
     var n2 = getElementById("2").value
     var answer = n1+n2
     alert(answer)
  }
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="form">
<input id="1" type="text" />
<input id="2" type="text" />
<input type="button onClick="calculate()" value="Go" />
</form>
```

I am not sure where I went wrong, Can someone help please?

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't start ID's with numbers - in HTML4 and CSS it [isn't allowed](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html), in HTML5 it is allowed, but it's not good practice to do so.

Also, *in this* context it is illegal in HTML5 - as an ID starting with a number [requires at least one letter afterwards](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

So, firstly replace the numbered ID's with letters/words.

---

Apart from this, you need to fix the syntax errors mentioned below:

Replace `getElementById("id").value` with `document.getElementById("id").value;`

and also replace `<input type="button onClick="calculate()" value="Go" />`

with `<input type="button" onClick="calculate()" value="Go" />` (notice there was a closing `"` missing for `"button"`).

**Here is a working** [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mubd8/1/).

---

Here is the code used in the jsFiddle:

**Javascript:**

```
function  calculate() {
   var n1 = document.getElementById("aItem").value;
   var n2 = document.getElementById("bItem").value;
   var answer = n1+n2;
   alert(answer);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="form">
   <input id="aItem" type="text" />
   <input id="bItem" type="text" />
   <input type="button" onClick="calculate()" value="Go"/>
</form>
```

Comment: @user125697 Interesting that starting IDs with numbers is allowed now in HTML5; however, the IDs here are still completely illegal in both CSS AND HTML5 - because HTML5 requires "at least one character" in IDs: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @SamCreamer Hey! Feel free to accept my answer if it helped at all (check this for how to do it -http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<input id="val1" type="text" value="100" />
<input id="val2" type="text" value="200"/>
<input type="button" onclick="calculate()" value="Go" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function  calculate() {
          var n1 = +(document.getElementById("val1").value);
          var n2 = +(document.getElementById("val2").value);
          var answer = n1+n2;
          alert(answer);
         }
```

This will add the 2 numeric values entered rather than concatenating them.